# 「あと3日だな」 means what exactly?

Tags: word-usage, time

This is based on a listening exercise I'm trying to understand.

In this exercise, we don't know what day it currently is, but an event is planned for Saturday.

One speaker says:

> あと[3日]{みっか}だな…

My assumption is this this means:

> 今日あと、3日である

So, from this, can I assume today (in the exercise) is Tuesday? Or Wednesday? Or something else?

Comment: I wonder if this question has a precise answer in Japanese. If someone told me in English that an event was 'three days to go' I couldn't say with certainty what day that event was on.

Answer (score 1):

> So, from this, can I assume today (in the exercise) is Tuesday? Or Wednesday? Or something else?

No not really. II just means 3 days of time. It could refer to a point of time in the future, the past or could even mean a duration of time. Since it's a conversation, your assumption is probably correct but requires more context.

Comment: The future or a duration of time make sense, but it specifically says *後*三日, so I can't really think of a situation where the past would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

"There are three days left". Considering that Saturday is the day of the event, if we go back three days, "today" would be Wednesday.